# Silverstripe detect language and redirect on home

Tags: php, redirect, silverstripe

On my clients site using silverstripe 3 I'm trying to establish a homepage redirect based on users language.

This is my first time working with this cms so I got the information to change in the `mysite\code\pages` folder a file called `StartPage.php` with the following code

```
class StartPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

   public function init() {
      parent::init();

      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/' . $ip));

      if ($data->country_code == 'PL') {
         $this->redirect('pl/start', 301);
      } else {
         $this->redirect('en/home', 301);
      }
    }
   }
}
```

This has yielded no results and the site still redirected to `/en/home`, so I've tried to force the redirection in any case by leaving only `$this->redirect('pl/start', 301);` Still no results.

So by dabling further I edited the `_config.php` file and added those lines at top

```
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($currentpage == '/' or $currentpage =='') {

  $lc = ""; // Initialize the language code variable
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
      $lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
  }
  if($lc == "pl"){
      header("location: /pl");
      exit();
  }
  if ($lc == 'de') {
      header("location: /de");
    exit(  );
  }
  else{
      header("location: /en");
  }  
}
```

This works somewhat good, for example at chrome desktop the language is redirected correctly but on mobile chrome and Firefox it's still redirected to the English page.

Comment: _“but on mobile chrome and Firefox it's still redirected to the English page”_ - and you are sure you explicitly configured those two browsers to request a different preferred language …?

Comment: (Your first approach is not something you’d want to do on every page load to begin with, making an external API call each and every time, is going to slow things down considerably. If anything, this call should be made only once, and the result then stored into the user’s session.)

Comment: Thank for your response. I double checked in private mode and the language change works there (in FF and chrome mobile). I'm not familiar with this CMS so it's a hacky approach and right now it's the place I've seen anything. The first approach (StartPage) theoretically should work only on the home page and the redirect but for some reason that's not the case - I've checke if the page is loaded and it is but the redirect hasn't worked out.

Comment: The silverstripe-fluent module detects locales, you might find some inspiration from this code: https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent/blob/4.4/src/Middleware/DetectLocaleMiddleware.php

Comment: @RobbieAverill thank you for the link, to bad this isn't present in the 3. version of the framework. Right now I've noticed that all redirections seem to work on private mode and when the page cache was emptied - so I guess some cookie data is invoked when visiting the site.

Comment: Yes, if you have a session cookie then there won't be any HTTP caching used

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The client accepted that the language switch would be overridden by the cookie settings. The 3 uses the `RootPageController` as the default controller set in `routes.yaml` file and there was the bit for changing languages